# Unset session variable on page reload / setup but exclude AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, session

I'm currently trying to unset a session variable in WordPress if the page get's reloaded. I've tried a lot but it's not working like I want it. This is my function:

```
/**
 * Unset filter session if page get's reloaded
 */
add_action( 'wp', 'unset_filter_session' );
function unset_filter_session() {
    //Reset sessions on refresh page
    unset( $_SESSION['expenditure_filter'] );
}
```

It's working but it's working too good. Because when I reload the `content-area` in WordPress via AJAX, the session get's unset too which should be avoided:

```
jQuery('#content-area').load(location.href + ' #content-area>*', '');
```

So how can I do the unset of the session just on page load and exclude AJAX reloads?

Comment: I'd keep in mind that sessions don't work on all hosts, and are incompatible with a lot of caching mechanisms, with an added server overhead, which is why WP uses cookies and user meta

Comment: User meta is not possible for not registered users. Cookies might be a solution but what if the user disabled cookies?

Comment: I wouldn't expect any site to be able to track what I'm doing if I set cookies, which is kind of the point. At that point you could create table entries or posts and pass around a transaction ID, but then you would need the users consent to store data about them to comply with data protection legislation, else it could be illegal in some states/countries/continents, e.g. California, or the EU

Comment: Additionally, you can use URLs, a filtered view can have a filter endpoint on the end so it remains unique, this also improves compatibility with fullpage caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`wp_doing_ajax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_doing_ajax/) like so:

```
function unset_filter_session() {
    if ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        //Reset sessions on refresh page
        unset( $_SESSION['expenditure_filter'] );
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

*You can check the answer's revision for this update part..*

### UPDATE #2

Sorry, I didn't realize that you're loading a page fragment (`#content-area`) using the [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method. Or that you're not using the `admin-ajax.php` to handle the AJAX request.

So if you're *not* using the [`wp_ajax_{action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax__requestaction/) or [`wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv__requestaction/) action, or with the way you do the AJAX request, you can check whether the `X-Requested-With` header is set and that its value is `XMLHttpRequest`, and if so, you can cancel the session unsetting, like so:

```
function unset_filter_session() {
    if ( empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ||
        'XMLHttpRequest' !== $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) {
        //Reset sessions on refresh page, if not doing AJAX request
        unset( $_SESSION['expenditure_filter'] );
    }
}
```

That should work because jQuery always sets that header, unless you explicitly remove it — or change its value.

See the `headers` option on the `jQuery.ajax()` [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` is always added, but its
>   default `XMLHttpRequest` value can be changed

**Note: The header name is `X-Requested-With`, but in the superglobal `$_SERVER`, its key is `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. I.e. *Don't* use `$_SERVER['X-Requested-With']`.**

### UPDATE #3

As suggested by [Lawrence Johnson](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/22714/lawrence-johnson), you (ahem, we) should use [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php):

```
function unset_filter_session() {
    if ( 'XMLHttpRequest' !== filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' ) ) {
        //Reset sessions on refresh page, if not doing AJAX request
        unset( $_SESSION['expenditure_filter'] );
    }
}
```

(but I kept the previous code for reference)

Comment: This is not working, sadly :(

Comment: I haven't actually tested the code, but I'll see if I can come up with another solution. However, as an aside, you could try [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) in JavaScript.. but yes, JS has to be enabled on the browser and that `localStorage` / `sessionStorage` is actually supported and again, enabled.

Comment: I think the problem will be still the same if I use cookies or sessions because the unset get's called independently from the type of it. So the main problem is the check if it's an AJAX call or not - which seems to be not working with the if thing

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `wp_is_doing_ajax()` only returns true for queries to `admin_url('admin-ajax.php');`

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson, not necessarily. `wp_doing_ajax()` simply checks if `DOING_AJAX` is defined and that it evaluates to `true`. So it can be defined from any other files - e.g. in a custom plugin/theme file. Plus, WordPress [says](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-settings.php#L464) "Ajax requests should use `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`" - i.e. in WordPress, AJAX actions should be registered via `wp_ajax_{action}` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` actions and handled by the `admin-ajax.php`.

Comment: @SallyCJ, what I mean is that for what he is doing, `DOING_AJAX` is not going to be set to true. I'm not aware of any requests to WP that set `DOING_AJAX` to true aside from calls to `admin-ajax.php`.

Comment: Also, as for the AJAX calls going through `wp_ajax_` methods, I agree with you, but this looks like its for a single page app. His approach for dynamically loading content using this method is not abnormal; still, I probably would've broken the content out into includes and create an ajax handler for retrieving them.

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceJohnson, it made me realize of the `jQuery.load()` being used when you said "single page app". Your answer/approach is good, but I'd simply check for the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header. :)

Comment: @Mr.Jo, please check the updated answer. I hope the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` trick works for you. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ, it sounds like our answers are in alignment now. I would recommend using `filter_input` over querying `$_SERVER` directly, though. It is a fundamentally safer way to retrieve values that could potentially be manipulated by a malicious user, and in your case you could reduce the condition since it will return null for not found or false for invalid.

Comment: Once again, +1 for that @LawrenceJohnson, and thanks a lot for helping :) (I've updated the answer)

Comment: Looks great. upvoted

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could consider doing is adding a header variable to your AJAX requests. Even a `GET` or `POST` param would likely to the trick. Perhaps something like this:

```
/**
 * Unset filter session if page get's reloaded
 */
add_action( 'wp', 'unset_filter_session' );
function unset_filter_session() {
    //Reset sessions on refresh page
    if (!filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'isContentLoader', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) {
        unset( $_SESSION['expenditure_filter'] );
    }
}
```

And then

```
jQuery('#content-area').load(location.href + ' #content-area>*', { isContentLoader: 1 });
```

Comment: I won't include it in the answer since it doesn't fit the question, but, if it were me, I wouldn't be storing something in session that is only supposed to live within the active page. It'd be much easier to maintain consistency by storing the variables in your JavaScript and posting as needed for server-side processing.